# Configuration of the PR completion comment "Completing Pull Request xxxxx and the associated work items"

Tags: azure-devops

Whenever a PR is completed for a task/story/bug on our kanban, the comment

> "Completing Pull Request xxxxx and the associated work items"

is added automatically.

Basically I want to remove this, but can't find any instructions through Googling. Hoping someone here is able to help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in this option. If it is checked then the comment will appear automatically on the work item that is linked to the pull request. Unfortunately doesn't seem to be an option to not post the comment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Configuration of the PR completion comment “Completing Pull Request xxxxx and the associated work items”

AFAIK, there is no such out of box settings to achieve this function.

As a bold guess, there is an extension [WorkItem Updater](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlueBasher.bluebasher-workitemupdater) which can change work item while build executed. And then, add the task **WorkItem Updater** into your build. In that task, you can change it as any state and update the filed you want：

[image]

So, please check if you have such task in your Build Validation pipeline for you PR.

Comment: Good idea, but I can't find anything tied to this in the build validation pipeline unfortunately. It's a real mystery and it seems like whoever set it up is not in the team anymore.

Comment: Found the answer now, posted it as an answer.